# retrieving facebook userid ? Is it neccessary to have the signed request?

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am reading the facebook tutorial on creating a facebook app,

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/tutorial/

This is the code they are providing me with. They say to run it right after the user has accepted the permissions for my app to retrieve their information.

```
 <?php 

     $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

     $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

     $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
            echo ("Welcome User: " . $data["user_id"]);
     } 
 ?>
```

In the tutorial, they say to run the code after the user has accepted your app. Is this the only time I am able to obtain the user id ??? Is it necessary to have the signed_request or can I retrieve it later after they have already accepted my applications permissions

thanks

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can run this code anytime. If there is no `$data["user_id"]` you will be redirected to auth-page. From there you can choose to store either `$signed_request` or `$data` in a cookie or database. I also think I remember you can re-use `$signed_request` to run other queries against the API as well (in other functions or pages). UPDATE, you can store it in a session variable as well.

Answer (score 0):

I how I resolved it is like this. Facebook app always ask for a canvas url (secure and non secure) . I created a initiate url where when the user enters my page, they always enter the initiate url. this is where i set the following code. once i get the user_id i set it to a session and i redirect them to the dashboard of the app. there is where i can retrieve the user id and do what i want.

`www.yourwebsite.com/initiate/`

```
 $app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";

 $canvas_page = "YOUR_CANVAS_PAGE_URL";

 $auth_url = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
        . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page);

 $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

 list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

 $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

 if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
 } else {
        $data["user_id"];//Set the data to a session or db then redirect user to the page
         //you want them to be
 }
```